# How to Convert "Different" Multiple <Button> Functions to Generic Function with <Select>?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, upload

How do I make so that the load buttons java functions works from a   box with just one button, instead of two separate buttons that call on two "different" JavaScript functions?

**In other words clarify the question**:
I have two different functions that I need to fire, but from a  with one  to fire the function I choose in the selection box.

**Remember**: That the warnings and confirmation should still work, so there for I can not us one and the same load function for both options, because of the different warnings and confirmation.

**NOTE:** If it is possible without using jquery only with JavaScript that would be great, *but* if there is a solution with jquery then that will is good too as long as it works.

**Here are my JavaScript codes:**

```
function loadFileAsTextUNLIMITED()
{
    valid = true;
    if(document.fileTextBox.fileLoadName.value == "")
    {
    alert ("Please attach a file to upload")
    valid = false;
    }
    {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want upload unknown file? Remember that if you uploaded a file that is not a text or a web page source code file, it may hang up your computer or it may destroy the file when you try to save it. So if you chose to upload it this way, you are doing it on your own risk.") )
        {
        var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
            {
            var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;  
            };
        fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
        } else {
        window.alert("Good, it is advised you use the normal Load Text button and this button only if you have too. ")
        }
    } 
}



function loadFileAsText()
{
    valid = true;
    if(document.fileTextBox.fileLoadName.value == "")
    {
    alert ("Please attach a file to upload")
    valid = false;
    }
    {   
    var fup = document.getElementById('fileToLoad');
    var fileName = fup.value;
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    if(ext == "TXT" || ext == "txt" || ext == "HTML" || ext == "html" || ext == "HTM" || ext == "htm" || ext == "JS" || ext == "js" || ext == "CSS" || ext == "css" || ext == "PHP" || ext == "php" || ext == "DOWNLOAD" || ext == "download")
        {   
        var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;  
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
        } 
    else
        {
        alert("Upload a text or a web page file with source codes");
        fup.focus();
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here are those parts of my HTML codes for it:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" name="fileLoadName">
<input type="button" onclick="loadFileAsText();showFileSize();" value=" Load Text / Source Code Files ">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="loadFileAsTextUNLIMITED();showFileSize();" value=" On your own risk Load Any File Type">
<br>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" name="inputTextToSave" rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="Type your text here:"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a select (not sure if it's a radio button, dropdown select or what - off the top of my head i forget the syntax to grab that value, but it's easy to google) check out this post: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Once you have the value you will just write a submit (button click) function that looks something like this:

```
 function uploadDocument() {
   var selectValue = //get the select value and store it here
   valid = true;

  if(document.fileTextBox.fileLoadName.value == ""){
    alert ("Please attach a file to upload")
    valid = false;
    return;
  } 

  if(selectValue === 'unlimited'){
    loadFileAsTextUNLIMITED()
  } else {
    loadFileAsText()
  }   
}
```

Hopefully that is a little closer to what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I appreciate you answer and it truly helps me to clean up the codes a bit. But it does not answer to the question of how do I make the two buttons work as a `<select>` box with one button? @HolyMoly

Comment: maybe i don't understand the question as your wrote it - so to clarify, you have two different functions that you need to fire, but only want one button to fire both functions... is that correct?

Comment: Yes I will now edit the question so it is more clear. The functions are different yet similar.

Comment: But NOT fire from one and the same button simultaneous. They need to fire one function from one button by the `<option>` I chose from the `<select>` box. In other words the functions should be called by the <select><option> box wile the <button> should only fire what is selected.

Comment: oh, I see. So then you need to get the value of the select - and fire whichever function corresponds to that selection. I will update my answer real quick.

Comment: EXACTLY. That is the problem. I know I can not use "onclick" on an select option box with one button. Sow how do I solve that one?

Comment: But thank you for telling me how to shorten the codes. I really wanted to do some clean up anyway, because the entire page has too much codes. Here I only cut out what I wanted help with.

Comment: sorry, i was editing my answer and deleted some of the code accidentally! lol

Comment: one last thought, if you are using a dropdown select - you can use an onchange event listener to fire a function ;)  here is an old, but wordy example in an old answer i gave someone (scroll to the bottom of my answer, which if i wrote it now - would be a lot cleaner, lol) - the concept is what is important....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008998/javascript-update-price-select-onchange/39009697#39009697

Comment: I thought of that too, but that is the problem since I can not put `onChange` in `<select>` because that would mean that `onChange` calls one same function with different attributes. Logically `onChange` should be in `<option>` but it can not since it does not work in `<option>` or if it does then I do not know what to call on option as I can not call the same function the buttons calls on, because it should only work only when I fire it from the button and not automatically on change from the `<option>`. The `<option>` should only provide what option to load from when clicking the button.

Comment: I did search and I took a look in your example before I posted this help question. The problem I was facing with your example is that it calls on the same function with different attributes. But in this case I have two separate functions that should be chosen by choice from the menu and fired from the button.

Comment: As for changing your old answer, no problem. I did save on my laptop the old answer to ass maybe one day that could come in handy. I do want to make a clean up of my JS anyway so the old answer will come in handy for sure.

Comment: How ever I will test this new answer you gave here. It is a bit different then the answer you gave on the other page and this might work. I will answer to you after I test it and tell you how it went.

Comment: Your example has no fire button for the option. Also i tried it without it and with a submit button. No result it did not work. If there is no file I do get the alert "Please attach a file to upload". But when there is a file nothing happens. I added the selectValue this way `var selectValue = "TXTaSourceFiles";` did I do something wrong there?

Comment: Also my select box looks like this `<select class="" onChange="uploadDocument();" name="carType" id="group">
  <option value="TXTaSourceFiles" selected>Load Deafoult text or source code file</option>
  <option value="unlimited">Load on your own risk Any File Type</option>
</select>`

Comment: ' var selectValue = "TXTaSourceFiles" ` is not correct. The select should have an id or something, and you need to grab it by it's id or it's name and then with JS get the value of it. Copying and pasting what I wrote will not work for you - because I do not have all of your relevant code to write it in a way that will run correctly. An example of how to grab the VALUE of the select is `var selectValue = document.getElementById("unlimited").value;` 1) you get the select by it's id or it's name 2) you extract the value from it and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Now I used exactly `var selectValue = document.getElementById("unlimited").value;` and I even tried `var selectValue = document.getElementById("TXTaSourceFiles").value;` still nothing. Now it does not even show the alert anymore.

Comment: The select looks like this now `<select class="" onChange="uploadDocument();" name="carType" id="group">
  <option value="TXTaSourceFiles" id="TXTaSourceFiles" selected>Load Deafoult text or source code file</option>
  <option value="unlimited" id="unlimited">Load on your own risk Any File Type</option>
</select>`